# SQL query to return aggregations in a constant format, even when the categories are missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by, grouping

Is it possible with SQL Server to return table with a constant format?

Let's say we have the following raw data:

```
DATE       |  CATEGORY  |  VALUE
---------------------------------
01.01.2022 | Category 1 |   10
01.01.2022 | Category 1 |   20
01.01.2022 | Category 1 |   33
01.01.2022 | Category 3 |   15
03.01.2022 | Category 1 |   10
03.01.2022 | Category 2 |   20
03.01.2022 | Category 3 |   50
              (...)
```

And the desired output would be:

```
DATE       |  CATEGORY  |  VALUE
---------------------------------
01.01.2022 | Category 1 |    63
01.01.2022 | Category 2 |     0
01.01.2022 | Category 3 |    15
02.01.2022 | Category 1 |     0
02.01.2022 | Category 2 |     0
02.01.2022 | Category 3 |     0
03.01.2022 | Category 1 |    10
03.01.2022 | Category 2 |    20
03.01.2022 | Category 3 |    50
              (...)
```

Please notice that in the desired outcome there's a date present that's missing in the raw data, as well as sum of VALUE are 0 when the category is not present for a given date in the raw data.

Comment: You need to set up a 'calendar column' for all days between your first and last days and then `left join` to that.

Comment: Use a Calendar table, `CROSS JOIN` that to your `Category` table (assuming you have on) and then `LEFT JOIN` to the table above.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Contiguous dates table
DECLARE @dates TABLE(dt date) ;   
DECLARE @dateFrom date;
DECLARE @dateTo date;

select @dateFrom = (Select DateAdd(day, -1, Min(date)) from Agg);
select @dateTo = (Select Max(date) from Agg);

-- Query:


WHILE(@dateFrom < @dateTo)
BEGIN
   SELECT @dateFrom = DATEADD(day, 1,@dateFrom)
   INSERT INTO @dates 
   SELECT @dateFrom
END

-- Category table 
DECLARE @categories TABLE(category nvarchar(20)) ;
insert into @categories values ('Category 1'),('Category 2'),('Category 3');

-- This cte helps in creating the constant output required 
with cte1 as (
select dt, category from 
@dates cross join @categories

) 
select cte1.dt as [Date], cte1.category, Sum(coalesce(yourTableName.value,0)) as Value
from cte1 left join yourTableName
on cte1.dt = yourTableName.[Date] and cte1.category = yourTableName.category
group by cte1.dt, cte1.category
order by cte1.dt, cte1.category
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

However, though it solves the primary issue, now the query does not want to execute due to the large execution time.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH  ctedate AS
(
    SELECT d= v2.d * 10 + v1.d
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v1(d)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v2(d)
)

Select b.date, a.category, sum(coalesce(a.value,0)) from 
yourtablename a 
cross join
 (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ctedate.d, '2022-01-01') date
FROM ctedate
ORDER BY ctedate.d) b 
group by b.date, a.category
```

Comment: This would still miss the January 2nd date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script with solution using [cte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

1. Calculate the min date and the max date
2. then make a calendar (cte1) with all dates between (min date) and (max date) using [recursivity](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/)
3. get the list of all category => cte2
4. make a [cross join](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cross-join/) between cte1 and cte2 ==> cte3
5. make a left join between cte3 and the table data (@mytable), replace Null values by 0

   declare @mytable as table (date date,category varchar(50),Value int)

   insert into @mytable values
   ('01/01/2022','Category 1',10),
   ('01/01/2022','Category 1',20),
   ('01/01/2022','Category 1',33),
   ('01/01/2022','Category 3',15),
   ('01/03/2022','Category 1',10),
   ('01/03/2022','Category 2',20),
   ('01/03/2022','Category 3',50);

   declare @mindate as date, @maxdate as date

   select @mindate=min(date),@maxdate=max(date) from @mytable;

   with
   cte1 as (select @mindate mydate  union all select dateadd(day,1,mydate) from cte1 where dateadd(day,1,mydate) <= @maxdate),
   cte2 as (select distinct(category) from @mytable),
   cte3 as (select mydate,category from cte1 cross join cte2),
   cte4 as (select mydate date ,cte3.category,isnull(value,0) value from cte3 left outer join @mytable t on cte3.mydate=t.date and cte3.category=t.category )
   select * from cte4